# Программно изменить таймер пробуждения в управлении электропитанием

Tags: c#, windows

На удаленных филиалах стоят компьютеры (XP, 7, 10), интернет там ужасный. Их необходимо периодически включать для прокачки данных. Проблема в том, что на них всех отключен таймер пробуждения. Вопрос как это включить на всех. Смотрел через групповые политики, так там таймеры пробуждения менять нельзя. Смотрел через реестр при изменении таймера там каждый раз появляется новая строчка в виде хеша. И менять их смысла нет. Вот и вопрос можно ли как то включить таймер через программу (лучше на c#).

Права доменного админа у меня есть, так что распространить через групповые политики проблем не составит. А там на месте есть кому их ребутить.

Comment: Через `powercfg.exe` не удастся сделать вызвав с нужными параметрами?

Comment: powercfg.exe если используем импорт экспорт создает еще одну схему. Эту схему надо ручками выбирать. Не подходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ: запускаем cmd под админом а там пишем

```
powercfg /SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_CURRENT 238c9fa8-0aad-41ed-83f4-97be242c8f20 bd3b718a-0680-4d9d-8ab2-e1d2b4ac806d 1
```